# Issue on Exporting JSON Object to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I am trying to export a JSON object to an HTML Table by using this code:

```
JSONSelect.forEach(selecRow, options, function (queryResult) {
    var sem = $.trim(JSON.stringify(queryResult, null, ' '));
    console.log(sem);

   $.getJSON('sem', {/*somedata*/}, function(json_data){
    var table_obj = $('table');
    $.each(json_data, function(index, item){
         var table_row = $('<tr>', {id: item.id});
         var table_cell = $('<td>', {html: item.data});
         table_row.append(table_cell);
         table_obj.append(table_row);
    })
    $('body').append(table_obj);
})
```

Please be informed that the JSONSelect is a plugin to query JSON data and I have stored the result in variable call `sem`. Eventually the `sem` look like this on `console.log(sem);`

[image]

I tried to export the `sem` to table by using above `$.getJSON()` method but I am not getting any table or even error on result/ console. can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here or is there any better idea to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for the wrong thing. The purpose of it is to retrieve JSON data from a remote source... and based on what you explained, you are already doing that with JSONSelect.

**Update** Based on your fiddle, it's clear that the queryResult that you get from JSONSelect is in fact one of the items - therefore you no longer have to do a `$.each` within. You should be doing something like this:

```
JSONSelect.forEach(selecRow, options, function (queryResult) {
    var table_obj = $('#myTable'),
        table_row = $('<tr>', {id: queryResult.name}),
        table_cell = $('<td>', {html: queryResult.author});

    table_row.append(table_cell);
    table_obj.append(table_row);
    $('body').append(table_obj);
})
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65hYy/) (please note that I replaced the table object selector - you will have to adapt it to fit your solution).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $.getJSON('URL', function(json_data){
        //no need for parsejson
        //use the json_data object

        var table_obj = $('table');
        $.each(json_data, function(index, result){
             var table_row = $('<tr>', {});
             var table_cell1 = $('<td>', {html: result.firstName});//result.yourDataAttributes
             var table_cell2 = $('<td>', {html: result.lastName});
             var table_cell3 = $('<td>', {html: result.age});
             table_row.append(table_cell1,table_cell2,table_cell3);
             table_obj.append(table_row);
        })

    });
    </script>
</head>
    <body> 
    <table id=""></table> 
    </body>
```